# How to insert image into database using razor(asp.net)

Tags: mysql, asp.net, razor

I am working on web pages(razor) asp.net using Webmatrix environment.
I am trying to insert uploaded image path into database so i confuse which variable should be pass to query to make the path inserted into table.
here is my code:

```
int numFiles = Request.Files.Count;
  string fileName="";
     if(IsPost)
     {
         for(int i =0; i < numFiles; i++) {
        var uploadedFile = Request.Files[i];
          if (uploadedFile != null) 
        { 
        fileName= Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName); 
        uploadedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/documents/", fileName))); 
        } 
        }
     }

Here is my query to insert into database but i dont know what how o insert the path into database.

int numFiles = Request.Files.Count;
  string fileName="";
     if(IsPost)
     {
         for(int i =0; i < numFiles; i++) {
        var uploadedFile = Request.Files[i];
          if (uploadedFile != null) 
        { 
        fileName= Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName); 
        uploadedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/documents/", fileName))); 
        } 
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

To store image in database you just need insert particular image location (in the form of string) on the server of your image into database table.

for example: to store "photo.jpg" in the database
first upload it to your server,
next get the path of image at your server,
save the path in the database table(ex: INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (....,Path,...);)